# Contract creation: The transaction has been reverted to the initial state

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, smartcontracts, nft, binance-smart-chain

creation of HomestayNFT pending...
creation of HomestayNFT errored: Error occured: revert.

revert
The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.

```
constructor(
        uint256 noRooms,
        uint256 firstTwoHourPrice,
        uint256 hourPrice,
        uint256 dayPrice,
        uint256 monthPrice
    ) ERC721("HomestayNFT", "HNFT") Ownable(msg.sender) {
        _startTime = block.timestamp;
        _noRooms = noRooms;
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < noRooms; i++) {
            _roomValidity[i] = true;
        }
        _price[0] = firstTwoHourPrice;
        _price[1] = hourPrice;
        _price[2] = dayPrice;
        _price[3] = monthPrice;
    }
```

I try to deploy a smart contract with params 20,5,2,30,300 and it reverted.
I try to deploy by thirdweb and remix but all of them reverted.
If you know the answer, can you help me to understand why. Thanks

Comment: Based on the error you provided seems like you are trying to send ETH along with the transaction. Is this correct?